# How to keep track of the object created in a class

Tags: java, algorithm, constructor

This question was asked to me in an interview. He wanted to know that suppose we have created a object for a class and like this multiple objects were created. So if any object has already created then how i can keep track of the objects created.

My approach:-
1:- Firstly I thought to use the count to get the track of object created but later i was not able to explain him clearly.

After coming back home i tried to search on the internet but i could not find any specific result but today when i was searching the same question, I got one thing that is somewhat related to that question. It's CONSTRUCTOR'S AS PRIVATE.

Am i thinking correctly and if not please let me know how can i approach this problem.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the question. Are you asking how to keep track of the number of instances created of a particular class? Why not increment a static counter in the constructor?

Comment: actually that guy asked me simply like suppose i am creating objects for  a class (at run time) and there can be multiple objects in a class so how can i keep track of the created object. if it is created then i can say like this particular object created twice

Comment: Still not sure what you're saying. You can't create a particular object twice.

Comment: So if not, then can i keep track of that?

Comment: Keep track of what??

Comment: I think i got it shmosel. Thanks

Comment: You Question is quite unclear. He may have been asking you to track the count of objects instantiated (static variable or singleton to track an incrementing number). Or he was asking about how to gather the new objects (add to a Collection). Or he may have been asking about the [identity of each of your instantiated objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)). Three different questions. If you do not understand those questions, let alone the answers, you may need to do more study and practice before applying for jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> So if any object has already created then how i can keep track of the
>   objects created.

Define a `static` field in the class to store the tracked information and update it at each time **any** constructor is invoked.
For example to keep trace of created instance and their datetime creation, by assuming you have a single declared constructor :

```
public MyClass{

   private static final List<TrackedInformationForMyClass> trackedInformationForMyClasses = new ArrayList<>();

   public MyClass(){

        // tracking 
        trackedInformationForMyClasses.add(new TrackedInformationForMyClass(this, LocalDateTime.now()));
        // usual code
       ...
   }
}
```

Where `TrackedInformationForMyClass` is a model class that carries the tracked information :

```
public class TrackedInformationForMyClass{
    private LocalDateTime datetime;
    private MyClass myClass;

   public TrackedInformationForMyClass(LocalDateTime datetime, MyClass myClass){
       this.datetime = datetime;
       this.myClass = myClass;
   }
   ... getter and helpful methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other *simple* way but to keep a variable and provide **at least** one constructor in the class. Now in this constructor, increment variable once each time.

If you are conscious about thread safety then use AtomicInteger type and that should solve your problem.

Comment: ok, so like whenever an object will be created then the variable count will be increased.